# Using Subroutine for output instead of a function

Tags: excel, vba, function, parameter-passing, subroutine

I thought at this point that the role of functions and subroutines was very clear to me. But now I am not so sure... I see it written all the time

"Functions can return values / subroutines cannot return a value."

and

"a function can only return a single value" (I realize they can return arrays and such too).

But it seems as though I can effectively "return a value from a subroutine" if I pass the "result" variable into the subroutine... Is this considered a "poor practice?" or am I missing some other key concept here...

Method # 1 (Using a Function):

```
Sub test1()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer

    x = 2
    y = 3
    z = test2(x, y)

End Sub

Function test2(var1 As Integer, var2 As Integer) As Integer

    test2 = var1 + var2

End Function
```

Method # 2 (Using a Subroutine):

```
Sub test3()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer

    Call test4(x, y, z)

End Sub

Sub test4(var1 As Integer, var2 As Integer, var3 As Integer)

    var1 = 2
    var2 = 3
    var3 = var1 + var2

End Sub
```

Comment: Those parameters are passed `ByRef` (the default, as opposed to `ByVal`) and as such this is the expected result. Most, if not all times, you want `ByVal`, and as such you should be explicit about it.

Comment: Function may have a return type and sub - no and if you create a sub to register your function with `Application.MacroOptions` it will be available on the spreadsheet with `=test2(x, y)` in the cell.

Comment: So if I am not interested in using my functions in a cell... Then it seems I could effectively always use subroutines instead of functions... That doesn't seem right... How do I know when I should make one vs the other.

Comment: When you want to *return* something, use a `Function`. When you want to *do* something, use a `Sub` (and make sure you specify `ByVal` for your parameters unless you are absolutely sure you want `ByRef`).

Comment: You can, but why would you? It just makes your code unclear. If you want a result from a routine, it should be a function, unless you have a really specific reason for it not to be (which would be unlikely as a rule).

Comment: No issue AFAIK. the whole use of Sub vs Function is a bit of a black box really. I tend to choose firstly based on whether I would want to allow the routine to be called via a worksheet function (UDF etc) or whether it could be called by a worksheet button etc, then secondly by whether I need to pass variables to or from the subroutine (generally if there are any variables used in or out, I tend to go with a Function otherwise use a Sub)

Comment: @Tragamor I disagree with your last sentence. The use of parameters should not affect whether a `Function` or `Sub` is used.

Comment: So... In my example... Both methods accomplish adding x and y together and result in z = 5. But as a rule of thumb I should do this using method # 1, which is to make it a function. Is this right?

Comment: ^ YES..........

Comment: @BigBen feel free to disagree, it won't change how I code

Comment: @Tragamor, but it might change how OP codes, which may be more important in this case.

Comment: If anything, you should dispense with subs in favor of functions. There is almost always *something* which can be returned (e.g. some sort of status code) which can be ignored when you don't need it. Some languages such as C get by with just functions. Some of this is really a matter of taste. For a nice discussion for some of these issues I recommend the book "Code Complete" by Steve McConnell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it is bad practice to change the value of a parameter. Just look at you examples - it is obvious that your function does something with the 2 parameters and returns a value (which you write to `z`). In the second example, you don't see what will happen  unless you look to the subroutine - and not only to the function definition, you need to read the complete code so that you can tell what parameter will manipulated and what not.

In software development, when you call a subroutine, you don't want to look at this subroutine - and often it is even not available for you. Let the subroutine do it's job, but without any side effects.

> > Use a function whenever possible, it keeps your code much more readable. Trust me...

There are (very few) cases when you want to receive more than one result from a subroutine. In that case, I would advice to put explicitly the keyword `ByRef` in front of the parameter (even if in VBA this is technically not necessary because it's the default). And put a comment that tells why it is the case. You will thank yourself when you look at your code weeks, months or years later.

Comment: Thank you... My main concern is making my code readable months/years later.